# JAVA: executing Catch not try

Tags: java, netbeans, jform

```
private void rtrBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) depTbl.getModel();
        try{
            Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1","admin","root");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM dept;";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()){
                String dno = rs.getString("deptno");
                String dName = rs.getString("dname");
                String lc = rs.getString("loc");

                model.addRow(new Object[] {dno,dName,lc});

            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error In Connectivity");
        }
}
```

Im trying to connect my JForm to the mysql database but not able to connect to the database, continuously executing catch statement "Error in Connectivity", please help how should i resolve this issue..............................................................................

Comment: And what is the exception you're having? Print the exception in the `catch`.

Comment: no error its compiling and running but not able to retrieve the data from database

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line

```
Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
```

to

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

in your code

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is not correct -   Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");

The java.sql.Driver is an interface. You need to provide the correct jdbc driver class for you appropriate db.
Such as for Oracle -   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");